# JQuery - Deselect/ Click Off an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem. In chrome this works absolutely perfect. However, in browsers such as Firefox and internet explorer it does not. When clicked onto the game, it is then 'Selected' onto that attribute, and does not listen to my key listeners.
Here is a example of my site and what it does -> Please view it first on chrome then on firefox, but make sure you have clicked onto the game attribute. When you press 'T' on the keyboard, it should overlay the item with text. `http://imdoingwork.com/games/ageofwar.php`.
Here is a JS fiddle of some of the code I am using -> http://jsfiddle.net/4fZCR/.

I think I need a way to 'Unselect or click off' the game window in order for the key listener to work, however I have no idea how to do that.
If you have any ideas, or a better approach to the one I am taking please let me know.
If this was unclear, I apologize as I am new to JQuery.
Thanks for any suggestions!
Toby.

Comment: What you might be looking for is the [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) function.

Comment: @Qqwy First of all thank you for the suggestion. Hmm, that seems about right, would you have any idea how I could implement it into my code. I'm really new to JQuery haha.
Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/N2sZMPgV
Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) function. This will deselect an element after it was selected(by clicking or by using the TAB key).

As you want to prevent that clicking on the game selects it, you can add a handler that triggers when the game is clicked:

```
$('embed').click(function(){
  $(this).blur();
});
```

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work yet it still seems focused on the game. Could you edit my JS fiddle?
Sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="red">
     <embed id="fitvid777405" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://imdoingwork.com/games/ageofwarupdate1MzYx.swf"></embed>
</div>
<div class="blue hidden">
     <h1>WELCOME!</h1>
</div>
```

css

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
div.blue
{
    background: blue;
}

div
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').keypress(function (e){  
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if((key==116||key==84) && ($('.red:visible').length))
    {
        $('.red').css('display', "none");
        $('.blue').css('display', "block");
    }
    else{
        $('.red').css('display', "block");
        $('.blue').css('display', "none");
        }
});  
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly on jsfiddle. Do you think JavaScript will work?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.1
[jquery.com](http://jquery.com/). [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) does not work very well with some lines is not a replacement for browser

Comment: I'll try it later thank you all for the advice. If anyone has any more suggestions please let me know :). Thanjs